# 301 redirect in .htaccess where URL contains number in second segment

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

How can I do a 301 redirect in .htaccess where the condition is any 2 characters in the first segment followed by any number in the second segment. For example

```
google.com/en/51/something/else
google.com/fr/29/some-text
google.com/es/111/
```

to

```
google.com/en/product/51/something/else
google.com/fr/product/29/some-text
google.com/es/product/111/
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following to your .htaccess file in the root of your domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[^/]{2}/product/ [NC]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]{2})/([0-9]+.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1/product/%2 [L,R=301]
```